# Deriving gradient on unit 2-sphere using definition for Riemannian manifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, solution-verification, vector-analysis

The definition of the gradient $\nabla f$ of a function $f: M\to \mathbb{R}$ for $(M, g)$ a Riemannian manifold is given by $$g_x(\nabla f, V) = \mathrm{d}_x f(V)$$ at all $x\in M$ and vector fields $V$ on $M$. To determine the gradient on the unit 2-sphere $S$, we take a point $p = (\varphi, \theta)$, which has cartesian representation $(\cos(\varphi)\sin(\theta), \sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta), \cos(\theta))$, for $\varphi\in [0, 2\pi)$, $\theta\in [0, \pi)$. Then, for two vectors $v_1 = (\varphi_1', \theta_1')$ and $v_2 = (\varphi_2', \theta_2')$ in $T_pS$, we have that the inner product between $v_1$ and $v_2$ is $$g_p(v_1, v_2) = \sin^2(\theta)\varphi_1'\varphi_2'+\theta_1'\theta_2'$$ To see this, we can take the inner product of their cartesian representations at $p$: $v_1$ has the representation $$(\theta_1'\cos(\varphi)\cos(\theta)-\varphi_1'\sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta), \theta_1'\sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta)+\varphi_1'\cos(\varphi)\sin(\theta), -\theta_1'\sin(\theta))$$ and $v_2$ has a similar representation, with $\varphi_2'$ and $\theta_2'$ in place of $\varphi_1'$ and $\theta_1'$. Then, let's say that at $x$, $V$ has the direction $v_1$, so $$\mathrm{d}_x f(V) = \varphi_1'\partial_{\varphi} f(\varphi, \theta)+\theta_1'\partial_{\theta} f(\varphi, \theta)$$ This then implies that $$\nabla f(\varphi, \theta) = (\partial_{\varphi} f(\varphi, \theta)/\sin^2(\theta), \partial_{\theta} f(\varphi, \theta))$$ so that $$g_p(\nabla f(p), v_1) = \sin^2(\theta)\varphi_1'\cdot \partial_{\varphi} f(\varphi, \theta)/\sin^2(\theta)+\theta_1'\cdot \partial_{\theta} f(\varphi, \theta) = \mathrm{d}_x f(V)$$ But, [it seems like this has an extra factor of $\sin(\theta)$ in the denominator in the $\varphi$ component.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) Where did I go wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I realized myself that there actually isn't a mistake at all. If we want to choose an orthonormal basis aligned with our $(\varphi, \theta)$ coordinates at $T_pS$, then we need to pick $\hat{\varphi} = (1/\sin(\theta), 0)$ and $\hat{\theta} = (0, 1)$. Then, $$g_p(\nabla f(p), v_1) = \partial_{\varphi} f(\varphi, \theta)/\sin(\theta)\hat{\varphi}+\partial_{\theta} f(\varphi, \theta)\hat{\theta}$$ which is the formula given on Wikipedia.